# Best value of K when using K-Nearest Neighbors with Spectral Clustering

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, k-nn, spectral-clustering

I'm using scikit-learn's `SpectralClustering` class, which has the option of building its affinity matrix using a K-Nearest Neighbors algorithm. Is there any way to calculate an "optimal" value of K?